# Click outside an element not working on tablet and phone

Tags: javascript, tablet

I put a script on my page to hide all the elements with a particular class when the user clicks anywhere on the screen.
The code works perfectly on PC, but not on tablets and phones. I should use just Javascript, not jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClick(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.className == 'item active') {
            e.className = 'item none';
        }
        else {  
            var x = document.querySelectorAll('.item.active');
            for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                x[i].className = "item none";
            }
            e.className = 'item active';            
        }
    }

    function findClosest (element, fn) {
        if (!element) return undefined;
        return fn(element) ? element : findClosest(element.parentElement, fn);
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        if (document.querySelector('.item.active') != null){        
            var t = document.querySelector('.item.active').id;  
        }

        var target = findClosest(event.target, function(el) {
            return el.id == t;
        });
        if (!target) {
            var x = document.querySelectorAll('.item.active');
            for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
                x[i].className = "item none";
            }
        }
    }, false);

</script>

<div id="item1" class="item none" onclick="onClick('item1')">
    ...
</div>

<div id="item2" class="item none" onclick="onClick('item2')">
    ...
</div>  

...
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of JavaScript touch events library that overrides regular computer mouse events?

Comment: @KevBot No, Federico is right. I only used click event and nothing for touch.

Answer (score 0):

The click event works on PC because it is associated with the mouse click. However, on tables and phones, there's no click event. Instead you should use **touch events**. Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
      // Click outside logic
}
```